# SwiftUI: Change the start position for animated progress bar (or Shape drawing in general)

Tags: swift, swiftui

The code below begins to draw a rectangle from the bottom left corner. How can I change it to begin to draw from the top middle? Hopefully there is a simple setting I am missing here.

```
@State private var progress: Double = 0
@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        HStack{
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
                    .opacity(0.3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                    .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                Rectangle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.progress, 1.0)))
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                    .animation(.linear)
                    .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                    .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                        if(progress < 100){
                            progress += 0.1/10
                        }
                        else{
                            progress = 0
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the point of origin for the line by adjusting the rotation effect of the second rectangle by 90 degree increments. This will not cause you to start in the middle of a line, but it will shift which corner this animation fill begins in. If you want to start in the middle of a given segment, you will likely need to create a custom shape with intermediate origins in the middle.

Comment: @binaryPilot84 is correct. The animation starts at the lower-left because the `path` property of the standard `Rectangle` starts at the lower-left.  Rotating will just change which corner, but it will still start from a corner (and you can't trim outside 0 and 1, although maybe two overlapping trims could work in, but it's not nice). You need to make your own Rectangle with the path starting where you want. Unrelated, but if you overlay instead of zstack, you don't need to specify the frame in two places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to rotate it (moreover it might be not square), just create own rectangular shape with start point anywhere needed.

Demo prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct MyRectangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path {
            $0.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var progress: Double = 0
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                ZStack {
                    MyRectangle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
                        .opacity(0.3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 200, height:100)
                    MyRectangle()
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(self.progress, 1.0)))
                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        .animation(.linear)
                        .frame(width: 200, height:100)
                        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                            if(progress < 100){
                                progress += 0.1/10
                            }
                            else{
                                progress = 0
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```